# Clean Up GraphQL Response and Convert to JSON without edges and nodes

Tags: php, json, recursion, graphql, shopify

I am calling the [Shopify admin api](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api).

When I use the [REST API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference), I get beautiful JSON objects in my responses.

```
[{
 {
    "id": 7036594978985,
    "title": "7 Shakra Bracelet",
    "body_html": "<p>7 chakra bracelet, in blue or black.</p>",
    "vendor": "Company 123",
    "product_type": "Bracelet",
    "created_at": "2021-06-17T17:45:05-04:00",
    "handle": "chain-bracelet",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-23T20:08:21-04:00",
    "published_at": "2021-06-17T17:45:04-04:00",
    "template_suffix": null,
    "published_scope": "web",
    "tags": "Beads, Bracelet",
    "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Product/7036594978985",
    "variants": [
      {
        "id": 40671266963625,
        "product_id": 7036594978985,
        "title": "Blue",
        "price": "42.99",
        "sku": null,
        "position": 1,
        "inventory_policy": "deny",
        "compare_at_price": "44.99",
        "fulfillment_service": "manual",
        "inventory_management": null,
        "option1": "Blue",
    
      }
  },
  {
    id: 7036594978986
...
]
```

However, if I use [GraphQL](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference) I end up with a bunch of edges and nodes that don't play well with my front end JS.

```
{
  "products": {
    "edges": [
      {
        "node": {
          "description": "Sleek and black",
          "featuredImage": {
            "id": "gid://shopify/ProductImage/15464783282345",
            "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/1005/6873/products/bb20.jpg?v=1602116082"
          },
          "handle": "skirt",
          "id": "gid://shopify/Product/4773734482089",
          "images": {
            "edges": [
              {
                "node": {
                  "id": "gid://shopify/ProductImage/15464783282345",
                  "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/1005/6873/products/bb20.jpg?v=1602116082"
                }
              },
              {
                "node": {
                  "id": "gid://shopify/ProductImage/26072838406313",
                  "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/1005/6873/products/bb7.jpg?v=1612636091"
                }
              },
              {
                "node": {
                  "id": "gid://shopify/ProductImage/26072838373545",
                  "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/1005/6873/products/bb6.jpg?v=1612636091"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
```

I'd like to flatten the array a little bit by replacing all edges and nodes with the friendly minimal JSON  structure.

From this:

```
{
  "products": {
    "edges": [
      {
        "node": {
          "description": "Sleek and black",
          "featuredImage": {
            "id": "gid://shopify/ProductImage/15464783282345",
            "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/1005/6873/products/bb20.jpg?v=1602116082"
          },
```

To this:

```
{
  "products": [
      {
          "description": "Sleek and black",
          "featuredImage": {
            "id": "gid://shopify/ProductImage/15464783282345",
            "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/1005/6873/products/bb20.jpg?v=1602116082"
      },
```

I'd like to be able to call a recursive PHP function to replace all nodes and edges nested in the array.

I tried this, but I think it causes iteration issues.

```
public function parse_and_remove (&$arr) {
    
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (($key == 'edges' || $key == 'node') && (is_array($val) || is_object($val))) {
            $arr = $val;
            $val = $this->parse_and_remove($val);
        } else if (is_array($val) || is_object($val)) {
            $val = $this->parse_and_remove($val);
        } else {

        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

PART II

How is everyone okay with this kind of response in GraphQL?  It's a pain to work with on the front end where API responses are often consumed.  Don't give me the array of edges and the node then finally the object.  I just want that array of objects :)

Comment: what frontend problems? just `images.edges.map( {node} => <SomeImage key={node.id} url={node.originalSrc} />` - no need to 'flatten' :p  - you're not using pagination [on relations], I guess

Comment: There are a million different components and plugins that do not expect nodes and edges.

Comment: exactly? one specific? again, what FE [lib] might have a problem? flattening can be done in js `.map` oneliner, not worth the BE effort

Answer (score 0):

I finally created a function that did it.   It is terribly inefficient because every time I move a node up to replace the parent, I break and restart the entire loop in order to be able to parse the parent again.

```
$nice_data = $this->move_value_at_node_to_parent($response['body']['data'], 'node');
$nice_data2 = $this->move_value_at_node_to_parent($nice_data, 'edges');
```

the function:  (no indentation because I like prefer the ease of repetition with code alignment - * the foreach loops are nested)

```
public function move_value_at_node_to_parent($obj, $key_name) {

        // make array
        $obj_string = json_encode($obj);
        $arr = json_decode($obj_string, true);
        // do this a bunch to avoid index problems
        for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) { 
            if(!is_array($arr)) continue;
            foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
                if($key == $key_name) { 
                    $arr = $val;
                    break;
                }
            $arr2 = $arr[$key];
            if(!is_array($arr2)) continue;
            foreach ($arr2 as $key2 => $val2) {
                if($key2 == $key_name) { 
                    $arr[$key] = $val2;
                    break;
                }
            $arr3 = $arr[$key][$key2];
            if(!is_array($arr3)) continue;
            foreach ($arr3 as $key3 => $val3) {
                if($key3 == $key_name) { 
                    $arr[$key][$key2] = $val3;
                    break;
                }
            $arr4 = $arr[$key][$key2][$key3];
            if(!is_array($arr4)) continue;
            foreach ($arr4 as $key4 => $val4) {
                if($key4 == $key_name) { 
                    $arr[$key][$key2][$key3] = $val4;
                    break;
                }
            $arr5 = $arr[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4];
            if(!is_array($arr5)) continue;
            foreach ($arr5 as $key5 => $val5) {
                if($key5 == $key_name) { 
                    $arr[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4] = $val5;
                    break;
                }
            $arr6 = $arr[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5];
            if(!is_array($arr6)) continue;
            foreach ($arr6 as $key6 => $val6) {
                if($key6 == $key_name) { 
                    $arr[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5] = $val6;
                    break;
                }
            $arr7 = $arr[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5][$key6];
            if(!is_array($arr7)) continue;
            foreach ($arr7 as $key7 => $val7) {
                if($key7 == $key_name) { 
                    $arr[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5][$key6] = $val7;
                    break;
                }
            }
            }
            }
            }
            }
            }
            }
        }
        return $arr;
        
    }
```